# How to upload files to server using php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

```
$lastid_id = mysql_insert_id();
$folderpath = "Attachment/".$lastid_id."".$fileatt_name;
if ($uploaded) {
    copy($uploaded,$folderpath);
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachcopy"]["tmp_name"],$folderpath)) {
        $uploaded = $folderpath;
    }
}
```

Above coding works well in local system but this code con not upload file to server system,Please give any ideas.

Thank you...

Comment: Look at the permissions in your upload folder. Can the web server write to it? Also, consider formatting your code so it's easily readable here. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use phpinfo() to check these settings:

`file_uploads` should be 'on'

`upload_max_filesize` should be bigger than the file you want to upload

`upload_tmp_dir` if empty, it will upload your file to a default path

`post_max_size` should be bigger than the file you want to upload

and check if you have permission to write to your upload folder.

Comment: Thank you sir,your suggestion is correct i am missing the folder write permission in my server,now its work fine.